# Like button making me crazy

Tags: javascript

i have current javascript function:

```
public function savelikes() {

    if (empty($this->input->post('secrets_id'))) {
        redirect('');
    }

    $ipaddress = $this->input->ip_address();

    $secrets_id = $this->input->post('secrets_id');

    // check se già è presente il dislike

    $checkunlikes = $this->db->query('select * from secrets_unlikes
      where secrets_id="'.$secrets_id.'" 
      and ipaddress = "'.$ipaddress.'"');

    $resultcheckunlikes = $checkunlikes->num_rows();

    if($resultcheckunlikes >= '1' ) {
        echo "Already voted!";
        exit;
    }

    $fetchlikes = $this->db->query('select likes from secrets where id="'.$secrets_id.'"');
    $result = $fetchlikes->result();

    $checklikes = $this->db->query('select * from secrets_likes 
                    where secrets_id="'.$secrets_id.'" 
                    and ipaddress = "'.$ipaddress.'"');

    $resultchecklikes = $checklikes->num_rows();

    if($resultchecklikes == '0' ){
        if($result[0]->likes=="" || $result[0]->likes=="NULL") {
            $this->db->query('update secrets set likes=1 where id="'.$secrets_id.'"');
        } else {
            $this->db->query('update secrets set likes=likes+1 where id="'.$secrets_id.'"');
        }

        $data = array(
            'secrets_id' => $secrets_id,
            'ipaddress' => $ipaddress,
            'date' => time(),
        );

        $this->db->insert('secrets_likes', $data);

    } else {

        $this->db->delete('secrets_likes', array('secrets_id'=>$secrets_id,
                            'ipaddress'=>$ipaddress));

        $this->db->query('update secrets set likes=likes-1 where id="'.$secrets_id.'"');
    }

    $this->db->select('likes');
    $this->db->from('secrets');
    $this->db->where('id', $secrets_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
    echo $result[0]->likes;
}
```

Then in the page i have

```
<button onclick="javascript:savelike(<?php echo $item['id']; ?>);" style="cursor:pointer;" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4"><span class="btn-inner--icon"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> <span id="like_<?php echo $item['id']; ?>" class="btn-inner--text">
                        <?php if($item['likes']>0){echo $item['likes'].' Likes';}else{echo ' ';} ?>
                        </span></button>
```

If i click the button nothing happens, the like doesn't get updated/inserte din database.

This is the savelike called:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function savelike(secrets_id) { 
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "<?php echo base_url('Secrets/savelikes');?>",
           data: "secrets_id="+secrets_id,
           success: function (response) {            
              $("#like_"+secrets_id).html(response+"");
           }    
        });
     }

     function saveunlike(secrets_id) {  
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url('Secrets/saveunlikes');?>",
            data: "secrets_id="+secrets_id,
            success: function (response) {           
               $("#unlike_"+secrets_id).html(response+"");
            }   
        });
     }

</script><!-- Core -->

 <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js'); ?>"></script>
```

I don't know what else to try, i have the tables correctly set (secret_likes and secret_unlikes) but still doesn't work.

Tried to debug, changing everything and even more but nothing, i'm thinking to delete this current system and make my own because i can't go crazy.

Comment: When you say "nothing is happening" do you mean that your JS is never running? that your JS is running but not communicating to your PHP? or that your PHP is running but not correctly inserting into the database? I would start by putting logging statements at each point in the code to see where your values are what you expected and where they are not

Comment: What's an example value for `$item['id']`?